# how filter inside array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter only kumar "to" items`"_id" : ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042")` message from my query and expected result

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5191502a2f1b3ca33e000016"),
    "message" : "<p>sssdasd<br></p>",
     "subject" : "test message to nag",
"date" : ISODate("2013-05-13T20:42:19.349Z")
    }
```

from below collections

```
{
        "__v" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5191502a2f1b3ca33e000016"),
        "conversation" : [
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-05-13T20:42:19.349Z"),
                        "message" : "<p>sssdasd<br></p>",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5191502a2f1b3ca33e000017"),
                        "to" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042"),
                                "name" : "Kumar"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("503fdbfa294f6db74de649ea"),
                                "name" : "Anand"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "message" : "<p>reply</p>",
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-05-13T21:05:33.453Z"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5191559c7d2c386741000018"),
                        "to" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("503fdbfa294f6db74de649ea"),
                                "name" : "Anand"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042"),
                                "name" : "Kumar"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "message" : "<p>reply2<br></p>",
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-05-13T21:05:55.006Z"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("519155b1ca98b66641000014"),
                        "to" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("503fdbfa294f6db74de649ea"),
                                "name" : "Anand"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("503fdbfa294f6db74de649ea"),
                                "name" : "Anand"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "from" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("503fdbfa294f6db74de649ea"),
                "name" : "Anand"
        },
        "sent" : ISODate("2013-05-13T20:42:19.349Z"),
        "subject" : "test message to nag",
        "to" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042"),
                "name" : "Kumar"
        }
}
```

I was try with below query

```
 db.messages.find({'conversation.to._id':ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042")},{'subject':-1, 'conversation.message': 1,'conversation.to':1}).pretty();
```

But I am not get the expected result

Comment: you need to use $elemMatch projection operator.

Comment: can you please give me in detail because I try the same here db.messages.find({"conversation": { $elemMatch : {"to._id" : ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042")}}}).pretty(); i am not getting result

Comment: db.message.find({'conversation.to._id':ObjectId("5048d2e5fbdac48208000042")},{'subject':1, 'conversation.message': 1,  conversation : {  $elemMatch : {'to.name' : "Kumar"}}, 'conversation.to':1}).pretty();

Comment: its look good but I want to fetch the last item inside conversation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used aggregate framework I am able to get the expected result.

```
 db.message.aggregate(
                    { $unwind : "$conversation" },
                    { $match: { 
                                    "conversation.to.name" : "Anand"
                                    }
                    },
                    {
                      $sort: {
                                    "conversation.date" : -1 
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      $group: {
                                    _id:"$_id",
                                    msgSubject: {$first:"$subject"},
                                    msgDate: {$first:"$conversation.date"},
                                    latestmsg: {$first:"$conversation.message"}
                      }
                    }
    );
```

Please share if any different than above